# background image not getting loaded in SDL

Tags: sdl

i want to display an image(.png) in a frame in SDL.But,somehow only the frame appears and image does not get loaded.i am reading the image details from an XML file.this is the sample code i am trying:

Class myclass{

mysurface2(io.loadAndSet(myftndata->getXmlStr("backfile"), true) ),

myfframe(new fframe(img2,
                myftn->getXmlInt("backWidth"), 
                myftn->getXmlInt("backHeight"), 0, 0)),

myobjects()

{

```
      if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0) 
     {
       throw string("SDL Error!!!: ");             
     }

    atexit(SDL_Quit);
```

}

};

```
void myclass::drawImg() const {
SDL_FillRect( screen, NULL, SDL_MapRGB(screen->format, 255, 255, 255) );
SDL_Rect dest = {0, 0, 0, 0};
SDL_BlitSurface( screen, NULL, screen, &dest );
}
void myclass::move() 
 {
      while ( not done ) 
      {
        drawImg();    
        SDL_Flip(screen);
      }
 }
```

Please note: i have an entire framework,which i cannot give here.The above is my code that i am trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are blitting the screen to the screen, which is a zero-operation. You should change the first screen in the blit function to the SDL_Surface* that represents your image.
Are you using a library (e.g. SDL_Image) for loading the .png file? Because SDL can only load .bmp files.

Comment: hey got it,yes i just changed the screen to an image object!.thanks.